# Understand fast prime numbers generator

Tags: python, primes

```
def sieve_for_primes_to(n):
    size = n//2
    sieve = [1]*size
    limit = int(n**0.5)
    for i in range(1,limit):
        if sieve[i]:
            val = 2*i+1
            tmp = ((size-1) - i)//val
            sieve[i+val::val] = [0]*tmp
    return sieve
print [2] + [i*2+1 for i, v in enumerate(sieve_for_primes_to(10000000)) 
if v and i>0]
```

Can someone please describe how this code works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a *compressed* Sieve of Eratosthenes, it doesn't deal with even numbers, but instead only stores and checks odd numbers.  That's why to get from a sieve index to a number it does `2 * i + 1`. This cuts in half the amount of space needed to store the sieve.

It doesn't *select numbers starting from 2* but rather tacks 2 onto the front of the prime list afterward. It starts with 3 (`2 * 1 + 1`) and goes up to the square root. Rather than using a loop to mark composites, it neatly takes advantage of Python's slice capability:

```
sieve[i + val::val] = [0] * tmp
```

to set multiples to 0 (False).  However, these lines seem to incorrectly overshoot the target:

```
limit = int(n**0.5)
for i in range(1,limit):
```

As `limit` is an uncompressed value not expressed as an index which would be something like:

```
limit = int(n ** 0.5) // 2 + 1
```

My annotated version of this (corrected?) code:

```
def sieve_for_primes_to(n):
    size = n // 2  # allocate storage for odd numbers up to n
    sieve = [True] * size  # mark all odd numbers as prime to start
    limit = int(n ** 0.5) // 2 + 1  # int(sqrt(n)) as an index

    for index in range(1, limit):  # ie. number in range(3, int(sqrt(n)))
        if sieve[index]:  # if still marked as prime
            number = 2 * index + 1  # index to number conversion (1 -> 3)
            multiples = ((size - 1) - index) // number  # how many multiples from here to end of sieve
            sieve[index + number::number] = [False] * multiples  # mark odd composites/multiples False

    return sieve

print [2] + [2 * index + 1 for index, boolean in enumerate(sieve_for_primes_to(10000000)) if boolean and index > 0]
```

There may be another optimization that can be made here:

```
sieve[index + number::number] = [False] * multiples
```

This starts marking composite multiples at the next odd multiple of the current prime.  But this means 5 starts marking at 15 which was already marked composite by 3.  We can actually start marking composite multiples at the square of the current prime, 25.  Exercise for the OP, how would we modify this compressed representation code to incorporate this optimization?

Answer (score 1):

This is called the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) and the wiki page does a good job of describing it.

The gist of it goes like this:

You select numbers starting from 2 and going up, then you:

1. Mark the number selected as prime.
2. Remove all multiples of that number from your set to prevent them from being selected in the future.
3. See 1)